# Add tag to all posts in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, tags

I have a `wordpress` website(http://tondtondcartoon.ir/). I want to add some static tags to all post of my word press website.
Note that, i want to add these tags to old posts and feature posts not just new posts.

Thanks

Comment: Answer to duplicate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45069707/3680688)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a separate script and loop through all the posts and then use wp set post tags (see: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_tags).
In your script, include wp-blog-header.php so you can access WP functions.